# Discount amount is not showing in Summary

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am having an issue here. After applying discount, the amount is not showing in Summary on Checkout .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code it's work for me. or you can explain your code in detail so we can understand.
Thanks

app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml file

```
<container name="checkout.cart.totals.container" as="totals" label="Shopping Cart Totals">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>


                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>

                                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated Total</item>
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
```